# javascript Adobe Form copy text from field with comb

Tags: javascript, forms, adobe

I would like to copy text from a field that is a postcode to another postcode field on selecting "As Above" check box, currently it copies the address fields, not the postcode. The field is using the COMB option spreading the input over 4 boxes, I am thinking this is why my current script wont work on this field, the scrip I am using is

```
  //Set the source and destination vars:
      var source = this.getField("Tradingaddress");
      var destination = this.getField("Mailingaddress");

  //See if destination is empty and if so, insert source value
      if(destination.value==''||destination.value==null) {destination.value=source.value}
```

Any Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I used the same script as above, but before adding the custom script, i changed the field so it doesn't have a comb, and is just a standard field, added the script and worked, then went back into the properties of both fields and re-added the comb function and re-tested OK!~ :) Thanks for your help ME haha